# $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)/GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is not compact

Tags: general-topology, matrices, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)\subset M_{n+1}(\mathbb R )$ be given the subspace topology and identify $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ with the subset of $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$ consisting of the matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&A \end{bmatrix}$ with $A\in GL_n(\mathbb R)$ .Then I have to show that  $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)/GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is not compact in the quotient topology.

I understand  that $GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)$ is not compact itself,because it is not bounded.But I have no clear idea about what happens when I mod out by the subset mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The closed subset $\begin{bmatrix}b&0 \\ 0&A \end{bmatrix}/\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&A \end{bmatrix}\cong \Bbb{R}^*$ is not compact.

Comment: @reuns The idea of quotient topology is very new to me. Could you please clarify, exactly how do I know that the subset you mentioned is closed ?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}b&0 \\ 0&A \end{bmatrix}$ is closed and right $\begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&A \end{bmatrix}$ invariant

Comment: In addition to what reuns said: the set of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}b&0\\0&A\end{pmatrix}$ is closed, because it is the set $f^{-1}(0)$ of the continuous function $f:\operatorname{GL}_{n+1}(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, which maps a matrix $B$ to the vector $(b_{1,2},\ldots,b_{1,n+1},b_{2,1},\ldots,b_{n+1,1})$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$B\in GL_{n+1}(\mathbb R)\mapsto b_{11}\in\mathbb R$$ is continuous and constant on equivalent classes, so it factors thru the quotient giving a continuous **unbounded** function.  Therefore the quotient is not compact.

Comment: Could you please describe it a little bit ?